# prove $R \subseteq S \Rightarrow R^+ \subseteq S$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$R$ is an endorelation and given is that $S$ is Transitive.

I need to prove $R \subseteq S \Rightarrow R^+ \subseteq S$

Does anybody have hint to tackle this problem.

Comment: Isn't $R^+$ defined as the intersection of all transitive endorelations which contain $R$?

Comment: I am not sure about that